# Error installing TFS 2008 on Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to install Team Foundation Server using 2 machines:

Machine1: OS: Windows 2008 Server Installed applications: SQL Server 2008 SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services

Machine2: OS: Windows 2008 Server Installed applications: SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 WSS/Reporting Services connector

The plan is to install TFS 2008 on machine 2 but after a lot of struggle I'm getting an error 28805 while installing TFS. I've tried to apply every solution I was able to find on the web without success. Almost all solutions I've found so far target Windows 2003 and SQL Server 2005.

Has anyone been able to deploy TFS 2008 on a configuration as the one I've described?

Thanks,

Pedro

Comment: What's the text that does with that error number?  Error numbers are useless to most everyone.

Comment: This is the text: "Cannot finish the request on Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Server. Please check that Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services and Windows service are running and you have sufficient privileges on the data tier"

Comment: Finally did it restarted from scratch. This time did made sure not to install WSS and did not configure SSRS, and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install SQL Server **DO NOT** configure SSRS. You let the TFS install handle the SSRS configuration.

This was one the errors I was experiencing.

Try to reinstall SQL Server 2008 and **NOT** configure SSRS and see how that goes.

Comment: I just uninstalled SSRS and I'll try reinstalling without configuring it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL Reporting Services Config Tool, in the Database Setup tab, make sure you are using Windows Credentials.

[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/e15160fc-757a-46b1-9d8e-908aeb4e8c14)